# SQL stored procedure trying to select then put together URL var

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I have been trying to figure this out and just getting nowhere. I am trying to perform a select statement in a stored procedure and then piece together a URL in a set statement based on what vars come back. I think I am just missing something simple, but I have been looking at it so long I can't find it.

Here is the code:

```
DECLARE @accept_resp as Varchar(25) 
DECLARE @decline_resp as Varchar(25)
DECLARE @sms_response_message as Varchar(255)

SET @bk = LEFT(@messageBatchKey, 8);

SELECT @accept_resp = accept_resp, @decline_resp = decline_resp
FROM MESSAGE_LOG
WHERE message_log_id = @messageBatchKey

IF (@accept_resp <> '')
BEGIN
    SET @sms_response_message = 'To Select' + CAST(@accept_resp AS varchar(25)) + ', click http://w.e-wens.com/vf/a_r.cfm?a=' + CAST(@bk AS varchar(8)) + '&' + 'sd='/*** + CAST(s.sub_id AS varchar(50))***/;
END
```

I know there is a `@accept_resp` value, but when I try to evaluate it, its almost like it doesn't exist. But the other issue is `@messageBatchKey` seems not to be pulling up anything. But I know it is populated because

```
 SET @bk = LEFT(@messageBatchKey, 8);
```

is working. Am I not performing the right syntax in the select statement?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you so much!

Comment: can you please add where @messageBatchKey comes from?  also, can you tell me if you can confirm that the select statement is rigged to only return one record?

Comment: Procedural code is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: The @messageBatchKey is a alpha numeric ID. It is SQL Server. Thanks

Comment: Any ideas? I'm sure it is something simple. Thanks

Comment: What results are you getting, and what results are you expecting?

Comment: hey Eric, we are not getting any results. However when we enter the raw var where message_log_id = 'E7BE77DB-A072-4646-844D957632C310F9' it seems to work. It's almost like @messageBatchKey is being zeroed out somewhere